# Laravel Searchable additional conditions

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the Laravel Searchable plugin for couple of months and it's working fine.
As a new task in one of my projects, I have to add additional condition to the search.

So, my idea is if a user is blocked (it has status == 0) to not be displayed in the search result.

This is my code:

PageController:

```
public function searchMember(Request $request, $id)
    {

      $this->validate($request, [
        'query' => 'required',

      ]);

      $query = $request->input('query');

      $searchResults = (new Search())
          ->registerModel(User::class, 'first_name', 'last_name')
          ->perform($query);

      return view('user.search', compact('searchResults'));

    }
```

View:

```
<div class="result-count">{{ $searchResults->count() }} results found for "{{ request('query') }}"</div>
<div class="result">
  @foreach($searchResults->groupByType() as $type => $modelSearchResults)
    @foreach($modelSearchResults as $searchResult)
        <div class="article">
          <a href="{{ $searchResult->url }}">{{ $searchResult->title }}</a>
        </div>
    @endforeach
  @endforeach
</div>
```

It works fine but I want to add where() parameter, so I can display only active users (status 1).
I've read if I want to add conditions, I have to tweak the code and I've tried like this in my controller:

```
public function searchMember(Request $request, $id)
{

  $this->validate($request, [
    'query' => 'required',

  ]);

  $searchResults = (new Search())
     ->registerModel(User::class, function(ModelSearchAspect $modelSearchAspect) {
         $modelSearchAspect
            ->addSearchableAttribute('first_name')
            ->addSearchableAttribute('last_name')
            ->where('status', 0); // This won't work
     })->search($request->input('query'));

  return view('user.search', compact('searchResults'));

}
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\PageController::App\Http\Controllers\{closure}() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\ModelSearchAspect, instance of Spatie\Searchable\ModelSearchAspect given, called in...
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

EDIT:

OK, I've corrected the error by adding

```
use Spatie\Searchable\ModelSearchAspect;
```

on top of the controller.

How can I add condition into the searchResult?

Answer (score 0):

Try type-hinting in closure

```
$searchResults = (new Search())
     ->registerModel(User::class, function(\App\Http\Controllers\ModelSearchAspect $modelSearchAspect) {
        //...
     })->search($request->input('query'));
```

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for the suggestion. 
The error I was getting was because I forgot to declare the ModelSearchAspect on the top of the controller but I still cannot add that condition where()...

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this one as well, but finally figured it out with scopes (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#query-scopes). You can read more about them in the Laravel docs, but here is working code that leverages them (user and organization scopes).I am searching across 4 models and each model has the scope where I can pass in the variables from an object that I have set ($user).

```html
$this->results = (new Search())
->registerModel(\App\Models\Meeting::class, function (ModelSearchAspect $modelSearchAspect) {
     $modelSearchAspect
          ->user($this->user->id)
          ->organization($this->user->organization_id)
          ->addSearchableAttribute('subject');
})
->registerModel(\App\Models\Note::class, function (ModelSearchAspect $modelSearchAspect) {
     $modelSearchAspect
          ->user($this->user->id)
          ->organization($this->user->organization_id)
          ->addSearchableAttribute('note_title')
          ->addSearchableAttribute('note_content');
})
->registerModel(\App\Models\Document::class, function (ModelSearchAspect $modelSearchAspect) {
     $modelSearchAspect
          ->user($this->user->id)
          ->organization($this->user->organization_id)
          ->addSearchableAttribute('document_note');
})
->registerModel(\App\Models\Task::class, function (ModelSearchAspect $modelSearchAspect) {
     $modelSearchAspect
          ->user($this->user->id)
          ->organization($this->user->organization_id)
          ->addSearchableAttribute('task');
})
->perform($searchterm);
```